# Sort a list of lists based on an internal list variable in R

Tags: r, list, sorting, vector

I have created an list of lists (let's say `parentList`) using a vector in R. `parentList` consists of 100 lists `childList1`, `childList2` and so on. Each such `childList` consists of a list of elements (`grandChildVariable1`, `grandChildVariable2` and so on). All the lists and variables are unnamed, except the `parentList`.

I want to sort the `parentList` based on the second element (`grandChildVariable2`) of each of the `childList`. I am able to fetch the values of this variable using `parentList[[2]][2]`. But I am not very sure how to sort the entire list.

I am currently trying to sort it as follows:
`sorted_list <- parentList[order(sapply(parentList,'[[',2))]` but it is picking up only the second list element `childList2` and returns the following error: `unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. It's a bit easier to extract the values first and then use them to order the parent list.

```
childList1 <- list(grandChildVariable1 = 1,
               grandChildVariable2 = 10)
childList2 <- list(grandChildVariable1 = 1,
               grandChildVariable2 = 30)
childList3 <- list(grandChildVariable1 = 1,
               grandChildVariable2 = 20)
parentList <- list(childList1, childList2,childList3)

x <- sapply(parentList, function(x) x[[2]])

orderedParentList <- parentList[order(x)]
str(orderedParentList)
```

Comment: This is a maybe bit neater: x <- sapply(parentList, function(x) x[[2]])

Comment: Rather than the loop

Comment: Edit your answer to make this easier accessible. I also think it's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the root cause of the `unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'` issue. The reason was that some of the `childList` elements were NULL. When I verified that the `parentList` contained no NULLs, I was able to get the sorting done properly.

Using `sorted_list <- parentList[order(sapply(parentList,'[[',2))]` gave the correct output intended and the answer given by Cleland would also do the trick.